# 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'remove'

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, floating-point

I have an array of arrays and I'm trying to find the lowest non-zero value among them all.

```
minima = []
for array in K: #where K is my array of arrays (all floats)
    if 0.0 in array:
        array.remove(0.0)
    minima.append(min(array))

print min(minima)
```

This yields

```
AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'remove'
```

I thought `array.remove()` was the way to remove an element. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I think I've figured it out.
The `.remove()` method is a list method, not an ndarray method.
So by using `array.tolist()` I can then apply the `.remove()` method and get the required result.

Comment: Don't forget to cast back if you are doing more than simply echoing the result: arr = list(arr); arr.remove(<value>); arr = np.ndarray(arr)

Answer (score 4):

This does not directly address your question, as worded, but instead condenses some of the points made in the other answers/comments.

---

The following demonstrates how to, effectively, remove the value 0.0 from a NumPy array.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0]) # NOTE: Works if more than one value == 0.0
>>> arr
array([0.1, 0.2, 0. , 1. , 0. ])
>>> indices = np.where(arr==0.0)
>>> arr = np.delete(arr, indices)
>>> arr
array([0.1, 0.2, 1. ])
```

Another useful method is [numpy.unique()](https://numpy.org/doc/1.18/reference/generated/numpy.unique.html?highlight=unique#numpy.unique), which, "Returns the sorted unique elements of an array.":

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> arr = np.array([0.1, 0.2, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0])
>>> arr = np.unique(arr)
>>> arr
array([0. , 0.1, 0.2, 1. ])
```

Answer (score 1):

Just cast it to a list:

```
my_list = list(array)
```

You can then get all the `list` methods from there.

Comment: Don't forget to cast back if you are doing more than simply echoing the result: arr = list(arr); arr.remove(<value>); arr = np.ndarray(arr)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you [want .delete](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.delete.html):

```
minima = []
for array in K: #where K is my array of arrays (all floats)
    minimum = min(array)
    minima = np.delete(array, minimum)
    minima.append(min(array))

print(minima)
```

And it seems to work for me, hence:

```
In [5]: a = np.array([1,3,5])                                                                                                                                   

In [6]: a = np.delete(a, 0)                                                                                                                                         

In [7]: a
Out[7]: array([3, 5])
```

Comment: That's giving the same error: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'delete'

Comment: What version of numpy? The docs list a delete method (as I linked to).

Comment: I have version 1.9.2, which I believe is the most current one.

Comment: I have tried using `np.delete(array, 0.0)` but the 0.0 is still included in the output. So there is something wrong either with the if statement or the delete command.

Comment: You probably have multiple members that are 0.0. I've edited my solution to address this.

Comment: The page you linked to states (regarding the obj parameter), "Indicate indices of sub-arrays to remove along the specified axis." If the minimum value in the array happens to be 0, then your method works, but only because the value and its index are 0 (an array with one or more negative values is one way to prove this).